# Using Jsoup to parse search descriptions in SERPS (Google Results)

Tags: java, html, css, http, jsoup

I keep running into a problem whenever I try to scrape off searches from Google Search results. I am using Jsoup to pull out the HTML code, but I am unable to pull out the information from the webpage that I need. I am aiming to reach the descriptions of the information under the titles. Here is my code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;


public class internetSearch {
    public void retrieveFileInfo(String pulling) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            String proxyAdress = "1.2.3.4";
            int proxyPort = 1234;
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,       InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(proxyAdress, proxyPort));

            doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(pulling)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)")
                    .header("Content-Language", "en-US")
                    .timeout(0)
                    .get();

            System.out.println(doc.toString());
            Elements links = doc.select("div[class=g]");

            for (Element link : links) {
                Elements titles = link.select("h3[class=r]");
                String title = titles.text();

                Elements bodies = link.select("span[class=st]");
                String body = bodies.text();

                System.out.println("Title: " + title);
                System.out.println("Body: " + body + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've used many sources across the web in order to get my code. In the past, I used Selenium as well, but to no avail.

I continuously search through my outcome in order to find the class ".st" which it is under (in h3, span, .st), and I do not reach a conclusion.

Is it just simply Google jumbling up the code or am I missing something vital?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with [estivate](https://github.com/btheu/estivate/) (which is a Java DOM Parser with Annotations compatible with JSoup)

```
Document doc = // here your JSoup document grabbing

EstivateMapper2 mapper = new EstivateMapper2()

List<GoogleResult> results = mapper.mapToList(doc, GoogleResult .class);
```

with the defintion of GoogleResult as follow :

```
@Select("div.g")
public class GoogleResult  {

    @Text(select = "h3.r")
    public String title;

    @Text(select = "div.s cite")
    public String link;

    @Text(select = "span.st")
    public String body;

}
```

Comment: How do I add Estivate? I'm sorry, I don't understand how to connect one project to another..

Comment: 1) With Maven add the dependencies to your pom.xml <dependency><groupId>com.github.btheu.estivate</groupId><artifactId>estivate</artifactId><version>0.3.4</version></dependency>
2) Or add directly the jar (and all its dependencies) to your classpath from maven central http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.btheu.estivate/estivate/0.3.4